# Can't tag friends on uploading photo to user wall - Facebook iOS

Tags: post, tags, photo, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm having an issue on uploading photo and tag user's friend to Facebook user's wall. It returns unknown error

If I removed the tags param, it will work perfect.

This is the code I use to post photo and tag users

```
NSMutableArray *chunks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableDictionary *tagDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

for(int i=0; i < appDelegate.listFriend.count ;i++) {
      NSDictionary *friend = [appDelegate.listFriend objectAtIndex:i];
      NSString *type = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[friend objectForKey:@"type"]]; 
      if([type intValue] == 1) {

                    [tagDict setValue:[friend objectForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"tag_uid"];
                    [chunks addObject:tagDict];
      } 
}

[photoParams setObject:[chunks JSONString]  forKey:@"tags"];

 //test posting facebook's image's url
NSString *imagePath = urlPhoto;
NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:imagePath];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];

NSMutableDictionary *photoParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                    message, @"message", imageData, @"source", nil];              

[appDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/photos" andParams:photoParams andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:appDelegate.self];
```

Please help me to resolve that issue, All ideas are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: is this issues got solution if yes please share it with me....

Answer (score 0):

Check this Link from the facebook developer account. It worked well for me try yourself first if you want i can give the codes tooo.

[FaceBook Docs Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/photo/tags#publish)